# Are internally-geared hubs UCI legal?

Tags: internally-geared-hub, uci

Are internally-geared hubs UCI legal?  I am assuming no one would ever use one for a race since durability and reliability matter less in a pro race than weight and efficiency, but I am also assuming that the UCI nevertheless put some stipulation in its rules to address them, just because.  If so, what part of their code pertains to this?

Comment: “durability and reliability matter less in a pro race than weight and efficiency” – definitely not true for downhill MTB.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are the [UCI's rules governing bikes](https://assets.ctfassets.net/761l7gh5x5an/O6r9QjLvGlvydLeHxwLbN/cb56b4420d49bc92a1d536cd7e8655f8/1-GEN-20211001-E.pdf) (jump way down to 1.3). After a quick perusal, they seem to be silent on the subject of internally geared hubs or multi-gear mechanisms in general, which is surprising considering how detailed their rules on sock length are.

They do, of course, prohibit multiple gears on track bikes.

Comment: Good find!   I suspect IGHs are like cantilever brakes or knobbly tyres, perfectly legal to use but come with more downsides than upsides for a road-race situation so there's no advantage.

Comment: IGH don't allow quick road-side wheel changes. The simplest reason why they will not be seen in the peloton.

Comment: Your multiple gears on track bikes comment was subtly hilarious.